# JQuery - Find closest textbox on dropdown change

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

On the change of DropDown list, I'd like to use JQuery to find the closest / next Textbox.
The Product textbox has a dynamic ID so I can't reference it using #Product, hence why I'd like to find it's ID dynamically:

```
<div class="orderLineRow">
@Html.DropDownList("Products")

@Using Html.BeginCollectionItem("OrderLines")
    @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(model) model.Product)  
 End Using
</div>
```

The dropdown change:

```
$(function () {
    $("#Products").change(function () {
       ??

    });

});
```

Comment: The dynamicID of the textbox, are the ID's similar? What are some examples of the ID's produced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Products").change(function(){
           $(this).siblings("input[type='text']").css("background-color", "#ff0000");
    });
});
```

This works. [Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Hy6sX/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/Hy6sX/)

Comment: I tried alert($(this).closest("input[type='text']").val()); and it returned undefined :/

Comment: it's not working because $(this) has no position in the DOM... it's just a copy of the element. You'll have to select the ID of what you've selected again. I edited my answer.

Comment: hm.. it still isn't playing nice. How strange.

Comment: I updated my code. .closest() looks at parent elements, and then from that you would use a .find() to select the input...not what I expected. .next() only selects the next DOM element. .siblings() will look at all elements on the same level... assuming these are on the same level.

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery's .next() http://api.jquery.com/next/

i.e. $(this).next('textarea')

Though that assumings they are sibling elements. If not, check out the other functions http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/